# новый элемент массива в request laravel 5.8

Tags: массивы, laravel, request

Вот такую структуру получаю когда вывожу `dd($request->all());`

> array:16 [▼   "_token" => "5w00cUNRIgfgNVYIRW7ecJ2bid2PeG0Qn4VUIG62"
>   "ci_id" => "1"   "accesses" => array:3 [▼
>       "user" => "dsaddasda"
>       "password" => "adsds"
>       "link" => "ddasadssdas/dasadsd/daads"   ] ]

Как добавить новый элемент в массив "accesses"?

Comment: `$request->all() + ['key' => 'value']` или `array_merge($request->all(), ['key' => 'value'])`

Comment: Тут вариантов, по сути, только 2 - добавить в `request` эл-ты или добавить в массив уже после `$request->all()`.. Как именно добавлять зависит от поставленной задачи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = $request->all();
$array['accesses']['new_key'] = 'ваши данные';
```

Погуглив нашёл ещё один вариант, требует проверки, так как нет laravela под рукой

```
$request->request->add(['variable' => 'value']);
```

Comment: А чем то похожим на $request->input('accesses.new_key', 'ваши данные'); нету такого?

Comment: @Domilola, Вы из `$request->all()` достаете массив,  он не содержит методов, так что нет

Comment: а почему в случае с методом input работает вставка просто как новый элемент работает, а продолжение не додумали?

Comment: @Domilola поправил ответ